# How to add zeros into my file using Perl to make lines the same length?

Tags: perl

I'm a bit of a newbie to Perl and I have a text file that looks like this, with a row containing an integer, followed by two rows that contain a list of numbers separated by tabs `\t`. This is only a sample of the file, which repeats this sequence of integers and 2 rows of lists of numbers.

```
1
1.10E-40    0.000970842 0   
2.51E-27    5.89E-07    0.132602458 0.020980783 2.89E-05    1.37E-27
2
8.96E-11    0.066251575 0.025529498 0.00084864
2.51E-27    5.89E-07    0.132602458 0.020980783 2.89E-05    1.37E-27
```

I want to use Perl to make each of the rows that contain lists of numbers contain the same number of numbers (in this case, 6 numbers), therefore I'd like to insert zeros separated by tabs onto the ends of the rows with less than 6 numbers. I don't want to do this for the rows containing a single integer though.
Basically, I want the output to look like this:

```
1
1.10E-40    0.000970842 0   0   0   0   
2.51E-27    5.89E-07    0.132602458 0.020980783 2.89E-05    1.37E-27
2
8.96E-11    0.066251575 0.025529498 0.00084864  0   0
2.51E-27    5.89E-07    0.132602458 0.020980783 2.89E-05    1.37E-27
```

So that there's 6 numbers in each row (except the first of every three lines which I want to contain only one integer). I was thinking that maybe this would be possible through a word counting tool that could tell me how many numbers are on each row, and then somehow appending `0\t` onto each row the relevant number of times. I'm not even sure if it's possible to append to a specific line of a file though.

I also am not really sure how to count the words on a line of a file (I have never counted words before anyhow), but when I look for word count code, I see it looks something like this:

```
open(FILE, "<file.txt") or die "Could not open file: $!";

my ($words) = (0);

while (<FILE>) {
$words += scalar(split(/\s+/, $_));
}


print("words=$words");
```

However I must confess I don't really understand the mechanics of how this counts words, so I really don't know whether this is along the right lines and could be adapted to count for each row. The fact there's a 'split' in there makes me think it could be splitting into columns, and I'd have thought this isn't what I want.

Comment: What have you tried? What problems are you having? Please show us your code.

Comment: I haven't really got much to show - I have never done a word count before let alone a word count per line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while (<>)                   # read lines from STDIN
    my @line = split;        # create an array of fields
    my $flds = scalar @line; # get number of fields
    if ( $flds == 1 ) {      # print rows with one column, unaltered
        print;
        next;
    }
    print join "\t", @line;                # separate each field with a tab
    print "\t0" for ( 1 .. (6 - $flds) );  # add a tab and a zero, needed times
    print "\n";                            # print the modified line
}
```

To use, do:

```
try.pl < try.data
```

**UPDATE** for: *Is there a way to hard-code it into my script though?*

If you prefer to embed the input and output filenames into this script, do:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $filein  = "try.data";
my $fileout = "try.filtered";

open( my $fin,  '<', $filein )  or die "Can't open '$filein : $!\n";
open( my $fout, '>', $fileout ) or die "Can't open '$fileout: $!\n";

select $fout;  # set as default output filehandle

while (<$fin>) {
    my @line = split;        # create an array of fields
    my $flds = scalar @line; # get number of fields
    if ( $flds == 1 ) {      # print rows with one column, unaltered
        print;
        next;
    }
    print join "\t", @line;                # separate each field with a tab
    print "\t0" for ( 1 .. (6 - $flds) );  # add a tab and a zero, needed times
    print "\n";                            # print the modified line
}
```

Now, run as:

```
try.pl
```

Comment: Sorry if this is stupid but what do you mean 'to use'? Can you apply the script to the file directly using open file etc or are you saying it must be run from outside the script?

Comment: Ok never mind my previous comment, I found it will run from within a larger script if I open the file first. Your help is appreciated so much!

Comment: Might I ask, I'm trying to modify this code to print to an output file. I have done this for `print join` and the two print lines below by adding in `$filename` after the word `print`, but this doesn't work for the `print` within `if ($flds == 1) {`. I feel like it's a stupid question but how can I adapt this line to print to a file too?

Comment: *how can I adapt this line to print to a file too?* Let the shell do all the redirections. Do: `try.pl < try.data > try.filtered`. Whenever possible keep code as amenable as possible to external control (file redirections, environmental variables, run-time options and values read from configuration files). The less hard-coding the better.

Comment: _Is_ there a way to hard-code it into my script though? You see, I'm hoping to use the output file for the next part of the script and my thought is that it's preferable to run it as one script rather than several separate scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Based on OPs problem description the following script comes to mind

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# vim: ai ts=4 sw=4

use strict;
use warnings;

my $columns = 6;

while( <DATA> ) {
        my @data = split;
        push @data, (0) x ($columns - @data) unless @data == 1;
        print join("\t", @data) . "\n";
}

exit 0;

__DATA__
1
1.10E-40    0.000970842 0
2.51E-27    5.89E-07    0.132602458 0.020980783 2.89E-05    1.37E-27
2
8.96E-11    0.066251575 0.025529498 0.00084864
2.51E-27    5.89E-07    0.132602458 0.020980783 2.89E-05    1.37E-27
```

Output

```
1
1.10E-40    0.000970842 0   0   0   0
2.51E-27    5.89E-07    0.132602458 0.020980783 2.89E-05    1.37E-27
2
8.96E-11    0.066251575 0.025529498 0.00084864  0   0
2.51E-27    5.89E-07    0.132602458 0.020980783 2.89E-05    1.37E-27
```